# How to combine file and not minify them using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        shorthandCompacting: false,
        roundingPrecision: -1
      },
      target: {
        files: {
          'css/output.css': ['css/one.css', 'css/two.css']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin']);

};
```

just started using grunt.js today and just had a look at the documentation and the examples , i am using the following plugin:

**[CSS-CONTRIB-MIN](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)**

Now, My files get minifined into one , but what i really want is for them to only be combined into one and not minified. how do i achieve that ?

Comment: What about https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat?

Comment: @fynn can't i do it with the above plugin itself ?

Comment: Not quite sure. However, CSS-CONTRIB-MIN is a plugin to compress CSS files. Using this and then deactivating the compression part does not really make sense to me.

Comment: @fynn , not deactivating , its just that until i am in development , i would't like to use the min feature .

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) plugin for this task. Take a closer look at the GitHub documentation on how to configure the task (e.g. separator, banner, ...)

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: ['css/one.css', 'css/two.css'],
      dest: 'css/output.css',
    },
  },
});
```